# Can apps with root access the Internet without listing internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: root-access, internet, permissions

It's my understanding that, in order to access the Internet, apps must declare internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. If an app doesn't declare this permission, but I was to give said app root access, would it still somehow be able to access the Internet if it wanted to?

Comment: See [Can Applications With Root Access Modify Their Own Permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29402)

Comment: In short: apps with root access can do anything that's technically possible. They could even upload all your personal stuff to some server and then perform a factory-reset on your device. Or worse (if there is). Which is why one should take extra care when installing such apps (make sure those are.trustable).